# Default value for a state created by QuantumRegister

Tags: quantum-state, programming, qiskit, initialization

What's the default value for a state created by `QuantumRegister(1,'name_of_the_register')`? Is it a $|0\rangle$ or a $|1\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source code for [quantumregister.py](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/quantumregister.py) and [quantumcircuit.py](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py).

The default is $|0\rangle$. The code goes like:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
qr = QuantumRegister(1) 
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr)
```

By the way, if you're just beginning with Qiskit, you could check out [Dr. Moran's textbook](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Mastering_Quantum_Computing_with_IBM_QX.html?id=jCWGDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) (this specific example is covered in chapter 5, ~p. 83).